# Face Book Connect and Sign in with Twitter

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, twitter

How we can use Face Book Connect and Sign in with Twitter in asp.net website. Please provide if you have any sample application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Facebook Toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/FacebookToolkit) for Facebook Connect and [OAuthLib](http://oauthlib.codeplex.com/) for Twitter Signin. Both projects have sample code showing how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

For Facebook connect can follow this links:

[Facebook SDKs and Tools](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/)

[How to Integrate with Facebook Connect](http://devtacular.com/articles/bkonrad/how-to-integrate-with-facebook-connect/)

[Facebook Developer](http://facebook-developer.net/category/tutorials/)

For sign in with Twitter take a look on this links:

[Single-user OAuth with Examples](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/single-user-with-examples)

[Twitter OAuth With .NET](http://www.voiceoftech.com/swhitley/index.php/2009/03/twitter-oauth-with-net/)

[Tweet Posting from Asp.net using OAuth](http://dotnetguts.blogspot.com/2010/05/tweet-posting-from-aspnet-using-oauth.html)